# What does "Get a damn room!" mean?

Tags: interpretation, jokes

A moment in a movie went like this:

> A woman was sitting on a man’s lap and about to kiss him in her room which has extremely thin walls. Her neighbor shouted suddenly, "Just kiss already! Get a damn room!".

Does he mean "I wanna hear the sequel. But get another nice room for the sake of your own privacy." or "Get any another room! I don't wanna hear anything romantic from your room."? 
I'm wondering if the neighbor is willing to hear the woman's privacy or not, for he said "Just kiss already!" which sounds he wants her to kiss the man.

Comment: This appears to be asking about a joke that uses the phrase, making it extra difficult to understand (because it's being used in a way it “shouldn't” be used).

Answer (score 50):

This expression usually means: *Go somewhere more private if you are going to be so affectionate*. It's typically used as an admonition when a couple is making other people feel uncomfortable because they are being overly affectionate in a public setting.

I've never heard of the expression being used when the person saying the phrase couldn't see the couple. I'm assuming you saw this in a movie somewhere, and the neighbor could hear the couple talking just before they kissed. If so, it sounds like a somewhat humorous use of the phrase. The neighbor is essentially informing the couple, "Even though I can't see you, I can still hear you."

Comment: And note that the stock expression is "Get a room"; the insertion of expletives is optional.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and also for the stock phrase, too! Your answer helped me understand the situation in the movie.

Comment: I think Futurama did this joke better: https://youtube.com/watch?v=4rrLkF2zM2c